# Got an error on okhttp on Android expected null but was okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec

Tags: java, android, apollo, okhttp

I got this error. After get response from the api. (I think when the app reading the response because its related to Http1Codec). Anyone have any idea? It hard to reproduce as well.

(We use okhttp along with [ApolloGraphQL](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) )

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
expected null but was okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec

okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.streamFinished (StreamAllocation.java:304)
okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$AbstractSource.endOfInput (Http1Codec.java:386)
okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSource.read (Http1Codec.java:416)
okio.RealBufferedSource.request (RealBufferedSource.java:68)
okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept (HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:241)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain (RealCall.java:200)
okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute (RealCall.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run (NamedRunnable.java:32)
```

Comment: I have got a sneaking suspicion that there is some associated with this.  Care to share?

Answer (score 0):

Beware if you have response.body().string() in your watch list that will cause your code to fail. Since watch list will run automatically.

```
ResponseBody responseBodyCopy = response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE);
responseBodyCopy.string();
```

Comment: Apollo return as data. I think this error come from ApolloLib that use okhttp

Answer (score 0):

When we use response.errorBody() or response.body() it will use buffer.
So the value may vanished before we can get String

Instead of `response.errorBody().toString`

We better use

```
ResponseBody errorBody = Objects.requireNonNull(response.errorBody());
String errorString = errorBody.toString();
onFailure(new ApiError(response.code(), errorString));
```